# The intersection of $BB'$ and $CC'$ lies on Circumcircle.

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $A',B',C'$ three points such that $CBA'$ is equilateral and so on for $B',C'$. And Denote $\mathcal{C}_A,\mathcal{C}_B,\mathcal{C}_C$ be the three Circumcircle$ (see figure, sorry it's a photo form my mobile..) [image]

$F$ is defined as the intersection of $BB'$ and $CC'$, I need to prove that $F\in\mathcal{C}_k$ for $k=A,B,C$. I first prove that $\vec{BB'}$ and $\vec{CC'}$ have same length and the angle is $2\pi/3$. I cannot find anything for this question, it seems that I can parametrize my point $A(0,0$ and $B(1,0)$ and $z_C$ and works "analytically". I would like to find a solution more geometric.

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is one geometric approach you are looking for. Consider the rotation $\mathcal{R}$ around $C$ of angle $\pi/3$. $\mathcal{R}$ takes $B'$ to $A$ and $B$ to $A'$. Consequently, $BB'$ is mapped onto $AA'$. Therefore, the angle them is also $\pi/3$ (one is the image of the other under a rotation of an angle of $\pi/3$!). More specifically, $\angle B'FA = \angle B'CA = \pi/3$. This shows that $F$ belongs to $\mathcal{C}_B$. Argue similarly for the other two circles!

Comment: I cannot this why, this show that $F$ belongs to $\mathcal{C}_B$. I can argue as Martigan's anwers but I don't the 'link' between the angle of $B'CA$ and $B'FA$.

Comment: @Gato Those two angles are equal iff $B'CFA$ is cyclic (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#Characterizations)).

Comment: @Gato The point is, by rotation of $\frac{\pi}{3}$, to show that $BB'$ becomes $AA'$, and hence that the angle between $BB'$ and $AA'$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$. But this exactly both $B'CA$ (equilateral triangle) and $B'FA$ (defined by angle $BB'$ / $AA'$).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ptolemy's theorem which says that in cyclic quadrilateral the product of the diagonals is the sum of the the products of the opposite sides.

if we apply this to the cyclic quad $BA'CF,$  we get $$A'F \cdot BC = A'C \cdot FB + A'B \cdot CF$$ canceling out gets you $$A'F = FB+FC \tag 1 $$ similarly you can get $$B'F = FA + FC\\CF = FA+FB \tag 2 $$ once you have established  $$A'AF, B'BF, C'CF $$ are collinear(not too hard), we now have 
$$A'A= B'B = C'C = FA+Fb+FC. $$

$\bf p.s.:$ the point $F$ is called the fermat-torricelli point.

Comment: $F$ is defined as $BB'\cap CC$, not as a point that is on $\mathcal{C}_A,\mathcal{C}_B,\mathcal{C}_C$.

Answer (score 0):

An other answer is to see that if the angle between $BB'$ and $CC'$ is $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ (angle $BFC$), then it means that it is twice the angle $CA'B$, and thus that it is lying on the circumcenter of the triangle $CA'B$.

You do the same for the other angles and this is it!